# How to run graphql query in a loop until condition is not matched

Tags: node.js, graphql, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I am trying to run a graphql query to retrieve all products from shopify graphql api, but we can not query all data at once due to limited rate limit. So how can I query all data without facing the rate limit problem and effectively?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```js
const myproducts = await axios({
        url: `https://${req.session.shop}/admin/api/2022-01/graphql.json`,
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
          "X-Shopify-Access-Token": req.session.token,
        },
        data: {
            query: `
            query ($numProducts: Int!) {
              products(first: $numProducts) {
                edges {
                  cursor
                  node {
                    id
                    title
                    
                  }
                }
                pageInfo {
                  hasNextPage
                  
                }
              }
            }
            `,
            variables: {
              numProducts: 3
              
            }
        },


    });
```

Comment: Have you looked into pagination? https://graphql.org/learn/pagination/

Comment: Yeah, I looked into it, and I also understand it, but I am unable to do it practically using nodejs, I just need an example on how to do pagination and cursor for query all graphql product data in nodejs. It would be great help if you can provide an example

Answer (score 1):

If it is for Shopify, you should definitely check their documentation about pagination: https://shopify.dev/api/usage/pagination-graphql

You can use a "while loop" to iterate until a condition is met, in this case when "hasNextPage" is false. Here is an example of how I get all the products from a collection:

```
//Query
const getProdCollection =
  `query nodes($ids: [ID!]!, $cursor: String) {
    nodes(ids: $ids) {
      ... on Collection {
        id
        
        products(first: 50, after: $cursor) {
          pageInfo {
            hasNextPage
            endCursor
          }
          edges {
           cursor
            node {
              title
              handle
              id
              descriptionHtml
              
            }
            
          }
    
      }
      
    }
  }
}`



app.post("/api/getcollection", async (req, res) => {
    const session = await Shopify.Utils.loadCurrentSession(
      req,
      res,
      app.get("use-online-tokens")
    );

if (!session) {
      res.status(401).send("Could not find a Shopify session");
      return;
    }

    const client = new Shopify.Clients.Graphql(
      session.shop,
      session.accessToken
    );

    //Set cursor to null for first iteration
    let cursor = null;
    let allData = [];

    while (true) {
      // place you looping request here
      let prodCollection = await client.query({
        data: {
          query: getProdCollection,
          variables: {
            ids: [req.body['data']],
            cursor: cursor
            
          },
        },
      });


      //update nextPage and curpor
      let nextPage = prodCollection.body.data.nodes[0].products.pageInfo.hasNextPage;
      cursor = prodCollection.body.data.nodes[0].products.pageInfo.endCursor;
      let myProductData = prodCollection.body.data.nodes[0].products.edges;
      allData = allData.concat(myProductData);


      //Finish the loop here
      if (nextPage == false) {
        break;

      }
    }

    //send back data
    res.send(allData);
  });
```